# Codeigniter SELECT from another table as an array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

What i was hoping i would break some functions down and skipping running multiple queries all the time.

Now if i have a ONE-to-MULTI relationship between two tables.
`tbl_invoices` and `tbl_invoice_items`. Table `tbl_invoice_items` has a different row for each item for a specific order.

Would it be possible with a SINGLE query from Codeigniter to get the item from the `tbl_invoices` and all the `tbl_invoice_items` in an array in the same result ?

Basically JOIN the below queries

```
$this->db->select('*,tbl_invoices.id AS invoice_id');
$this->db->from('tbl_invoices');
$this->db->where('tbl_invoices.id',$invoice_id);
$data = $this->db->get();


$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tbl_invoice_items');
$this->db->where('tbl_invoice_items.invoice_id',$invoice_id);
$this->db->join('tbl_products','tbl_products.id = tbl_invoice_items.item_id','left');
$data = $this->db->get();
```

Also would it be able in a ONE-to-ONE relationship tables return the other table as a custom variable ?
Something like:
`SELECT tbl_clients.* AS client, tbl_invoices.* FROM...JOIN...WHERE...etc`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is a 3 table sql join (in answer to your primary question) Here is the SQL query which should answer your primary question

```
$queryStr = sprintf("SELECT * from tbl_invoices a 
    INNER JOIN tbl_invoice_items b using a.id = b.invoice_id
    INNER JOIN tbl_products c using c.id = b.item_id 
    WHERE a.id = '%s' ", $invoice_id);

$query = $this->db->query($queryStr);
```

Comment: i can see how this can work but this way i'll get a full array in return containing the invoice information for each item leading to too much useless information. Do you think it would be more efficient to do that or run one extra query ?

Comment: Teris - my 2 cents worth is - in today's environment, the choices are worth a lot of thought only if they are impacting your applications performance. 
You could ignore the extra data, which you will not 'see' in any case. Does writing an extra query cause you code maintenance overheads ?? Hope this helps you decide :)